# Saving Settings for Asp.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

I am wondering what is the best method to save application site wide settings for Asp.Net MVC 5 C#?

Settings like Application name that would be shared in the Layout view.

Like

© @DateTime.Now.Year @Website.name

I have the settings stored in a Name/Value pair in database using EF.

Other settings would include:

SMTP Username and Password
Port Settings

Theme
API Keys (Twitter,Yahoo, and Etc)
and other settings.

I do not want to store any of these settings in web.config

Was thinking of loading the settings from database into application cache.

Then load up local variables with the settings stored in application cache.

This way only make a trip to the database on each application restart instead of each request.

So about every 20mins or more, no less.

Plan on also using a repository.

Just need to know what is the best method to use in terms of application loading speed, performance, and security.

Also the settings will be editable through an Admin page.

Answer (score 3):

I agree, that storing the settings in the application cache are the best idea. However, I would mask the settings behind a static class with properties that pull from the cache, and fall back to the db if the cache isn't loaded. For example:

```
public static class AppSettings 
{
    private static void LoadSettings 
    {
        // This is where you would call the DB and populate the cache
    }

    public static string AppName
    {
        get
        {
            if (Cache["appname"] == null)
                LoadSettings();
            return Cache["appname"];
        }
    }
}
```

With this implementation, it is easy for you to call your application settings from anywhere in the code base, and have it act as desired.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion what you have mentioned would be the best way to achieve this.

If you have an admin page then storing them in the database seems like a sensible choice, and retrieving them within `Application_Start` and caching them within the application cache so you don't have to keep query the database.

From here I would then recommend configuring your IoC container to retrieve the settings from the application cache and then injecting them into your services, controllers etc where needed - rather than referencing the application cache directly.

This way you can mock your application settings accordingly whilst still reducing the dependency on the requirement for application cache in case you decided on an alternative solution at some point in the future.

```
public static class SettingsFactory
{
    private const string Key = "Application.Settings";

    public static ApplicationSettings Settings
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Application[Key] == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Application[Key] = LoadSettings();
            }

            return HttpContext.Current.Application[Key] as ApplicationSettings;
        }
    }

    public static ApplicationSettings LoadSettings()
    {
        // Return/create instance of your application settings from your database.
        return new ApplicationSettings();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class ApplicationSettings
{
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }

    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
}
```

Then configure your settings within your IoC container like so (this example is using StructureMap):

```
this.For<ApplicationSettings>().Use(SettingsFactory.Settings);
```

This way your application settings are only created when they're used, then cached within the application cache and returned from the cache from thereafter.

Comment: So on the right path :),  Now just the matter of actually getting this to work do you know of any webpages with actual examples on how to get this to work. Have the process down, now just need the implementation.  Surprise there are not any Nuget Packages or Frameworks with this already.

Comment: Yes, you are on the right path. I'll update my answer to include a rough example of how I would approach this.

Comment: I know this is quite old, but I just got to this and seems like a great solutions. However, I can't wrap my head around how to use cache with this. I may start my own question while I keep looking through Google, but hoping you can clear it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Broadly agree with both the solutions posted by JoeMighty and Charlie Pugh (upVoted accordingly).

Two further elaborations:
1)  Use the cache dependency where you can callback on item removed to cache the result so that in the callback you can repopulate (rather than leaving the first unlucky user doing all the waiting around when the item is first required).

[Here's a link to the MSDN article on the overload you'll need to use when adding the cache item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05kd8d77(v=vs.110).aspx)

2)  If you use a base implementation of controller you can add a call to override OnActionExecuting to put all of these settings into a known slot in the ViewBag (rather than pollute your view models all over the place or access the cache directly from your views), so.... something like

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    // get the item from the cache here (anon object used as a placeholder)
    this.ViewBag.settingsfromcache = new { valuex = 12234 }; 

    // in the view you should then, consistently, be able to access "@ViewBag.settingsfromcache.valuex"

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

Admittedly I tend to shy away from using the ViewBag / tempData etc at all costs, in some circumstances it's quite useful to have.